# Вывод содержимого папки

Tags: файлы, visual-c++

Программа с кодом

```
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
HANDLE hf;
hf=FindFirstFile(L"cfg\\*", &FindFileData);
if (hf!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    do
    {
        cout << FindFileData.cFileName << endl;
    }
    while (FindNextFile(hf,&FindFileData)!=0);
    FindClose(hf); 
}
```

лежит в одной папке с папкой cfg. А в папке cfg лежит папка lol и файл text.txt. Собственно их я ожидаю увидеть в выводе программы. Вместо этого выводится

```
0A4ECF
0A4ECF
0A4ECF
0A4ECF
```

Что не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, так `cFileName` типа массива `TCHAR`'ов. В зависимости от опций компиляции это может быть как просто банальная строка из `char`'ов, а может быть юникодовская строчка. С вытекающими последствиями для ее обработки `cout`'ом. Короче. Не конопатьте мозги. И конструируйте временный `std::string` из строки `TCHAR`'ов и выводите уже ее на экран.

P.S.: это и есть проблема с локалями, по сути.

Comment: @gecube, выбрал в настройках компилятора "Использовать многобайтовую кодировку" вместо "Символы юникода". Помогло :)

Comment: @gecube, ещё проблема: теперь выводит 
`
 .
 ..
 lol
 text.txt
`
Что за точки????

Comment: 1. `.` - текущая папка
2. `..` - каталог уровнем выше

используется для относительных путей (вроде .\\bla-bla-bla\\subdirectory\\file) и для перемещения по уровнем верх (как в консоли - `cd ..`)

Comment: @Кht,

> выбрал в настройках компилятора "Использовать многобайтовую кодировку" вместо "Символы юникода". Помогло :)

ну, это не совсем правильное решение... Т.к. если кто-нибудь программу пересоберет с юникодом, то она сломается. Еще вариант - вручную вызывать правильные версии ф-ций, например, ф-ция (по факту - макрос) `FindFirstFile` на самом представлена двумя ф-циями: `FindFirstFileW` (Unicode) и `FindFirstFileA` (ANSI). И в зависимости от опций компилятора выбирается какая-то определенная.